# Debugger not suspending debugee upon exception C++

Tags: c++, debugging, winapi, breakpoints

I made a very simple debugger in C++ and it seems to work alright except if I call `WaitForDebugEvent` with any value for `dwMilliseconds` besides `INFINITE` it doesn't suspend the debugee immediately.

I have an `if` statement that checks whether the exception address matches the address of the breakpoint I set `if(ExceptionDebugInfo.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress == lpBreakpoint)`.

Decrements `eip`(`wow64cntxt.Eip --;`), replaces the breakpoint(`int3`) byte with the original instruction(`WriteProcessMemory`), flushes the instruction cache(`FlushInstructionCache`), and then sets `eip` to point to the breakpoint I replaced with the original instruction(`Wow64SetThreadContext`).

Then it returns to the main debug loop(`break`) and continues debugging(`ContinueDebugEvent`).

```
case EXCEPTION_BREAKPOINT:
{
    WOW64_CONTEXT wow64cntxt = {0};

    wow64cntxt.ContextFlags = WOW64_CONTEXT_ALL;

    if(!Wow64GetThreadContext(hThread, &wow64cntxt))
    {
        printf("Error getting thread context: %lu\n", GetLastError());
    }

    //lpFunction is the address of a mov instruction I set a breakpoint on
    if(excDbgInfo.ExceptionRecord.ExceptionAddress == lpBreakpoint)
    {
        printf("EIP-Before: 0x%X\n", wow64cntxt.Eip);

        //Decrement eip value to point back to the opcode I wrote over with int3
        wow64cntxt.Eip --;

        printf("EIP-After: 0x%X\n", wow64cntxt.Eip);

        //original opcode I replaced with int3(0xCC)
        instr = 0x89;

        //replace the breakpoint with the original instruction
        if(!WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, lpBreakpoint, &instr, sizeof(CHAR), NULL))
        {
            printf("Error reversing breakpoint: %lu\n", GetLastError());
        }

        //Flush the instruction cache
        FlushInstructionCache(hProcess, lpBreakpoint, 1);

        //Set eip to previous instruction
        if(!Wow64SetThreadContext(hThread, &wow64cntxt))
        {
            printf("Error setting thread context: %lu\n", GetLastError());
        }

    }
    system("pause");
    //Return to main debug loop, ContinueDebugEvent...
    break;
}
```

If I use anything other than `INFINITE` with `WaitForDebugEvent` then `eip` is set to an address that executes some time after the breakpoint I set.

The problem is that if I don't use `WaitForDebugEvent` with `INFINITE` then `eip` has already gone past the breakpoint when the debugger catches the exception. Even if I have `WaitForDebugEvent` wait for 0 milliseconds, return immediately, the debugee still runs past the breakpoint.

This then results in an access violation, I'm guessing because the other half of the instruction I replaced with the breakpoint becomes a new opcode that modifies memory it isn't allowed to.

Here's my main debug loop:

```
while(1)
{
    WaitForDebugEvent(&dbgEvent, INFINITE);

    ProcessDebugEvent(&dbgEvent);

    ContinueDebugEvent(dbgEvent.dwProcessId, dbgEvent.dwThreadId, DBG_CONTINUE);
}
```

Any information, insight, tips, explanations, etc would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: hard say what is go wrong in your code, but when breakpoint exception was in wow64 code debugger view `STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT` (0x4000001F) but not `STATUS_BREAKPOINT` (0x80000003) and you can use "normal" context Get[Set]ThreadContext even with wow64 code

Comment: however ( STATUS_WX86_BREAKPOINT or STATUS_BREAKPOINT depended are your debugger 64bit or 32 bit)

Comment: By the way, I upvoted this when I made the indentation edit. The reason is because, even though this is a simple, face-palm kind of question, you asked it well and presented all the information necessary to allow someone to answer it. Thanks for doing that, and for reading our help. Welcome to Stack Overflow! (I wanted to say this because I see someone has downvoted it, and I want you to ignore that, because this is a perfectly valid question. If you keep asking questions like this, you'll have a fine time here.)

Comment: @CodyGray Thank you for the encouraging comment! I am sure I will refer back here often for more problems and maybe even to help others. StackOverflow is kind of intimidating at first, not gonna lie, and it's nice to have someone let you know you're doing something right. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `dwMilliseconds` parameter tells `WaitForDebugEvent()` how long to wait for a debug event to arrive:

> *dwMilliseconds* [in]
>   The number of milliseconds to wait for a debugging event. If this parameter is zero, the function tests for a debugging event and returns immediately. If the parameter is INFINITE, the function does not return until a debugging event has occurred

You need to check the return value of `WaitForDebugEvent()` to make sure you actually have a real debug event that needs processing:

> If the function succeeds, the return value is nonzero.
>
> If the function fails, the return value is zero. To get extended error information, call `GetLastError`.

For example:

```
while (1)
{
    if (WaitForDebugEvent(&dbgEvent, AnyValueHere)) // <--
    {
        ProcessDebugEvent(&dbgEvent);
        ContinueDebugEvent(dbgEvent.dwProcessId, dbgEvent.dwThreadId, DBG_CONTINUE);
    }
    ...
}
```

That being said, the `dwMilliseconds` parameter has no effect on how long the debuggee waits when a breakpoint is hit.  When the breakpoint is hit, the debugee stops immediately, and your debugger is notified.  This is clearly stated in the documentation:

[Debugging Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms679302.aspx)

> When the system notifies the debugger of a debugging event, it also suspends all threads in the affected process. The threads do not resume execution until the debugger continues the debugging event by using `ContinueDebugEvent`.

So chances are, `ProcessDebugEvent()` is simply not handling the breakpoint correctly, and then the debuggee is woken up only when you call `ContinueDebugEvent()` after done processing.

Comment: Much appreciated. It occurs to me now that I should have checked the return value of `WaitForDebugEvent`. **Facepalm**. It is working well now, thank you very much. :)